# Draw path on indoor map using geoJSON avoiding obstacles

Tags: google-maps, google-indoor-maps

I'm a CS student and I'm developing an Android app that uses Google Maps API. The problem is the map I'm working on is indoor and I'm facing problems when I want to draw a path from user location to specific location he chose, because Directions API doesn't work with indoor map.

And when using a drawPolyLine method it draws a line that passes through walls, bathrooms, and anything on its way. So to solve this problem I made a GeoJSON file with linestring and polygon of each obstacle in that map.

And now I want to use the available drawing methods along with the geoJSON file to read the points/polygon and avoid it while drawing the path on the map.

Could please give an idea or anything that could solve my issue?

Comment: This is hard to help with, because it is very broad, and is likely to close in its present form. If anyone were to try to help with the question as it stands, the answers produced would be necessarily vague, and may not be what you want or need. Could you perhaps work out what algorithm you need to plot a path, so that you have a spec to work to? If you can show diagram(s) as well to help your readers understand the nature of the problem, that might be useful.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.